# Decoding images from sounds in Voyager golden records

Tags: image-processing, audio, reference-request

I'm interested in a side learning project in decoding the images recorded as sounds in Voyager's golden discs (https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/golden-record/). The instructions to be able to decode these images were represented on the record's cover as you can see in the following explanation of the diagram:

[image: explanation of the recording cover diagram]

Specifically, the instructions about images are represented in the upper right-hand portion of the cover. The description I've found from the Jet Propulsion Laboratory is the following:

> The top drawing shows the typical signal that occurs at the start of a picture. The picture is made from this signal, which traces the picture as a series of vertical lines, similar to ordinary television (in which the picture is a series of horizontal lines). Picture lines 1, 2 and 3 are noted in binary numbers, and the duration of one of the "picture lines," about 8 milliseconds, is noted. The drawing immediately below shows how these lines are to be drawn vertically, with staggered "interlace" to give the correct picture rendition. Immediately below this is a drawing of an entire picture raster, showing that there are 512 vertical lines in a complete picture. Immediately below this is a replica of the first picture on the record to permit the recipients to verify that they are decoding the signals correctly. A circle was used in this picture to ensure that the recipients use the correct ratio of horizontal to vertical height in picture reconstruction.

What I don't understand from the cover diagram is the meaning of the two circles that appear over the descending ramps of the 3 sawteeth in the second picture. From the JPL's description, it seems they may represent marks related with the "staggered interlace" they mention, but I'd need more information to understand it completely.

Besides that, if you pay attention the marks are situated in different relative positions in each of the three represented signals.

I have a basic understanding of the interlace vs progressive scanning used on video signals or with static images to allow a progressive representation, e.g. when they are used in a web browser. However, I don't understand the interlace used in this context, nor how I should decode that "staggered interlace".

I would appreciate any explanation or additional references I could read.